# sklearn model.fit "setting an array element with a sequence."

Tags: python, scikit-learn, knn

I'm currently trying to call my model's train() function by passing my X and Y data and receiving this error `setting an array element with a sequence.`

I tried creating fake data anbd passing it and it works just fine.
fake data:

```
X = [[1,2,3], [2,1,3]]
Y = [0,1]
knn_model.train(X,Y)
```

But when passing the real data, I get the error.
The real data is the value of pixels extracted from images. I get the same data structure as the fake data above but for some reason I get the error.

The data is created by instanciating the variable `images = []` and then appending every array of pixels of each image.

In the debug console, here is both the fake data and the real data:

```
real data: array dtype('O') of list containing array dtype('uint8')
fake data: array dtype('int32') of list containing array dtype('int32')
```

The error received is when the function fit() is called and the error is

"setting an array element with a sequence."

train function:

`def train(self, X, Y):
        self.model.fit(X, Y)`

Comment: I would recommend splitting your real data in order to check if there is a specific image that throws the error. Could some image have less pixels?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. You gave me a really good pointer there @Mindcraft. A couple of the images returned None instead of the pixels values. I just removed them and everything works now.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is in the error message. Your model is expecting an array while you are sending a sequence/list. Convert your training data from sequence to array using `numpy` before you append it.

```
numpy.array([1.2, "abc"], dtype=float)
```

or

```
numpy.array([1.2, 1, 42, 46])
```

Comment: That's exactly what I thought at first. After testing a few other formats (like the "fake data" one), I realized I had the right format. Like I explained in my comment to Mindcraft, I actually had values that were None. +1 for the tip though, it might help others receiving the same error.